# How to get Current Absolute URL with Query String in JSF?

Tags: java, jsf, url

I am trying to get the absolute URL in my managed bean's action listener. I have used:

```
HttpServletRequest#getRequestURL() // returning http://localhost:7101/POSM/pages/catalog-edit
HttpServetRequest#getQueryString() // returning _adf.ctrl-state=gfjk46nd7_9
```

But the actual URL is: `http://localhost:7101/POSM/pages/catalog-edit?_adf.ctrl-state=gfjk46nd7_9&articleReference=HEN00067&_afrLoop=343543687406787`. I don't know why the parameter `artcileReference` get omitted.

Is there any method which can give me the whole URL at once? How can I get the whole URL with all query string?

Comment: Complicated answer, some monkey coding :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can reconstruct your URL manually by using `ServletRequest#getParameterNames()` and `ServletRequest#getParameter()` both available with the `HttpServletRequest` instance.

Here is a sample code I've used in the past for this exact purpose :

```
private String getURL()
{
    Enumeration<String> lParameters;
    String sParameter;
    StringBuilder sbURL = new StringBuilder();
    Object oRequest = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest();

    try
    {
        if(oRequest instanceof HttpServletRequest)
        {
            sbURL.append(((HttpServletRequest)oRequest).getRequestURL().toString());

            lParameters = ((HttpServletRequest)oRequest).getParameterNames();

            if(lParameters.hasMoreElements())
            {
                if(!sbURL.toString().contains("?"))
                {
                    sbURL.append("?");
                }
                else
                {
                    sbURL.append("&");
                }
            }

            while(lParameters.hasMoreElements())
            {
                sParameter = lParameters.nextElement();

                sbURL.append(sParameter);
                sbURL.append("=");
                sbURL.append(URLEncoder.encode(((HttpServletRequest)oRequest).getParameter(sParameter),"UTF-8"));

                if(lParameters.hasMoreElements())
                {
                    sbURL.append("&");
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        // Do nothing
    }

    return sbURL.toString();
}
```

Comment: @TapasBose ortherwise you won't have a valid URL if you have special characters example : parameter including one `&`

Comment: +1 and obviously acceptable answer. Thank you very much. I have posted similar solution, if you can take a look. Actually I was getting NPE from the `URLEncoder#encode` so I have handled that also I have considered the `HttpServletRequest#getParameterValues()` as there can be `param=value1&param=value2&param=value3`.

Answer (score 1):

Here I came up with my solution, taking idea of the answer given by Alexandre, considering that `HttpServletRequest#getParameterValues()` method:

```
protected String getCurrentURL() throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    Enumeration parameters = getServletRequest().getParameterNames();
    StringBuffer urlBuffer = new StringBuffer();
    urlBuffer.append(getServletRequest().getRequestURL().toString());

    if(parameters.hasMoreElements()) {
        if(!urlBuffer.toString().contains("?")) {
            urlBuffer.append("?");
        } else {
            urlBuffer.append("&");
        }
    }

    while(parameters.hasMoreElements()) {
        String parameter = (String)parameters.nextElement();
        String[] parameterValues = getServletRequest().getParameterValues(parameter);

        if(!CollectionUtils.sizeIsEmpty(parameterValues)) {
            for(int i = 0; i < parameterValues.length; i++) {
                String value = parameterValues[i];

                if(StringUtils.isNotBlank(value)) {
                    urlBuffer.append(parameter);
                    urlBuffer.append("=");                            
                    urlBuffer.append(URLEncoder.encode(value, "UTF-8"));

                    if((i + 1) != parameterValues.length) {
                        urlBuffer.append("&");
                    }
                }                                                                        
            }
        }                                    

        if(parameters.hasMoreElements()) {
            urlBuffer.append("&");
        }
    }

    return urlBuffer.toString();
}
```